# Formatting a date time and time from a textbox

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

Using VB.net, VS 2015.

I have a webpage where a user selects a date from a textbox with an ajax calendar extender.  They also select a start hour and start minutes from two drop down boxes.  The start hour will be between 00 and 23 and the minutes will either be 00 or 30.

I want to format the date and time to the following format -

> "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

I populate the variable with the following code.

```
Dim startDate As DateTime = txtStartDate.Text + " " + ddlHoursFrom.SelectedValue + ":" + ddlMinsFrom.SelectedValue
```

If we take the following as the selected data - Date = Today, Hours = 13 and minutes = 30 then startDate =

> ## 8/30/2016 01:30:00 PM

If I use `startDate = startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")`

I get

> ## 8/30/2016 01:30:00 PM

If I use  `Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact((txtStartDate.Text + " " + ddlHoursFrom.SelectedValue + ":" + ddlMinsFrom.SelectedValue), dateFormat, Nothing)` where I specify the date format as a string variable `dateFormat`

I get

> ## 8/30/2016 01:30:00 PM

I am sure I am missing something obvious but can anyone help?

Comment: Switch option strict on. Your code to populate the date variable is open to interpretation and casting

Comment: Doesn't affect anything, no difference to format when I hover over the variable

Comment: It must affect something, Option Strict will not let you assign a string to a DateTime

Comment: This line will also not compile: `startDate = startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")` you are creating a string from a date and assigning it back to the original date

Comment: doh! that was it, thanks